# How to use SUM aggregate function in case statement with two when conditions - Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I am using aggregate function SUM for two when conditions in SQL case statement, but getting error message as: SELECT Failed 3568: Cannot nest aggregate opration

```
SUM(CASE WHEN COL1 in ('x','y') THEN 1
         WHEN COL2 in ('a','b') then 2 ELSE 0 END) as Result
```

I tried various combination for SUM function position in above code but no use.

Can anyone please help me here?

Comment: that is probably not the code that outputs this error.

Comment: Please provide the full code with select and from statement